# How can I use the name of a string in the form of a string variable to retrieve that string from the XML files?

Tags: android

I want to use the string's name or label in the form of a string variable to retrieve that string from `R.string.nameOfString` but can't figure out how. In the method `getText()` which is used to get the string, it takes "resource id for the string as a parameter," and the resource id is an int. I'm not sure how the path in a string variable can be converted to this resource id so I can retrieve that string from the XML file.

Comment: You can check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

**1.Add it to `res/values/strings.xml` file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nameOfString">helloworld</string>
</resources>
```

**2.Use in your code**

```
String value = context.getResources().getString(R.string.nameOfString);
```

**Note**

You just change `context` to your current `context`(`Activity` or `fragment`)

Answer (score 0):

**1.Add it to res/values/strings.xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="nameOfString">stringvalue</string>
    </resources>
```

**2.Use this value in java file**

```
Textview.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.nameOfString));
```

Hope this will help you and instead of Textview use your textview name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getResources().getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)` method.
**Code to access a String Resource**

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("string_name", "string", getPackageName());
String str = getString(resId);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Res String : " + str);
```